# When to use QueryParser vs. TermQuery?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am studying Lucene and cannot get the difference between QueryParser and Term Query. It seems they are the same. Is this true? If not when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, they are not the SAME. The following are the individual description of each of them.

1) QueryParser **"parses"** the text-query and builds a Lucene-Query-Object. It takes in the text-query and builds a Lucene Query object based on that information.

[Look at this article](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html) which describes the way the QueryParser parses the text input and builds the corresponding Query object.

2) **TermQuery is a deliverable of QueryParser**, i.e. it is a type of Lucene Query. Lucene supports wide variety of queries like boolean query, fuzzy query, etc.. and TermQuery is the most basic form of a Lucene Query.

When to use what?

- Almost all the applications, from simple to advanced levels, use the QueryParser. Just pass in the text-input and it builds the corresponding Lucene-Query-Object out of that input.
- You can always build your own query using the TermQuery constructor. People usually build their own Lucene-Query-Objects while experimenting with different query types.

You may check this tutorial which has all the fundamental stuff you need to know while using Lucene : [Lucene in 5 minutes](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html)

Comment: Got it..Thanks for your in-depth answer.